# why python turtle dosen't work propably , it imports , it draws, but it crashes and can't do anything :(

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

program stops responding before i can do anything , window apears, draws stuf and then it stops responding . i know code is terible but i started two days ago.

```
import turtle

########### okno #################################################


wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("spejs inwajders")


########### obramowanie##############################################


border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.hideturtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)
for side in range(4):
    border_pen.forward(600)
    border_pen.left(90)


############ gracz ######################################################

player = turtle.Turtle()
player_speed = 15
player.penup()
player.color("green")
player.shape("triangle")
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0, -250)
player.setheading(90)



while (True):


    ########### ruszanie #################################################

    def move_left():
        x = player.xcor()
        x -= player_speed
        player.setx(x)


    ############ bindy #####################################################

    turtle.listen()
    turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")
```

if there is someone who knows whats goin' on it would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

If you just trying to move if left on left press then it could be like...

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("white")
wn.title("Hello Turtle")

border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.hideturtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(3)
for side in range(4):
    border_pen.forward(600)
    border_pen.left(90)
player = turtle.Turtle()
player_speed = 15
player.penup()
player.color("green")
player.shape("triangle")
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0, -250)
player.setheading(90)

def move_left():
    x = player.xcor()
    x -= player_speed
    player.setx(x)


turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")
turtle.done()
```

Comment: thanks , it wwork's , but what does turtle.done()   do.........so i know when i should use it

Comment: It is just to hold the screen. If you would be making simple turtle program of printing anything then screen will vanish after that.